# Why SceneKit on iOS 8 cannot compile my custom shaders?

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, scenekit, fragment-shader

I created a new project based on the Game template with SceneKit as game technology and Swift for the language. And I tried to use a custom shader. Here is the setup code:

```
var material = SCNMaterial()
var program = SCNProgram()

// Read the vertex shader file and set its content as our vertex shader
if let vertexShaderPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("VertexShader", ofType:"vsh") {
    let vertexShaderAsAString = NSString(contentsOfFile: vertexShaderPath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
    program.vertexShader = vertexShaderAsAString
}

// Read the fragment shader file and set its content as our fragment shader
if let fragmentShaderPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("FragmentShader", ofType:"fsh") {
    let fragmentShaderAsAString = NSString(contentsOfFile: fragmentShaderPath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
    program.fragmentShader = fragmentShaderAsAString
}

// Give a meaning to variables used in the shaders
program.setSemantic(SCNGeometrySourceSemanticVertex, forSymbol: "a_position", options: nil)
program.setSemantic(SCNModelViewProjectionTransform, forSymbol: "u_viewProjectionTransformMatrix", options: nil)

material.program = program

// retrieve the ship node
let ship = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("shipMesh", recursively: true)
ship.geometry.firstMaterial = material
```

The code of my vertex shader:

```
#version 300 es

uniform mat4 u_viewProjectionTransformMatrix;
in vec4 a_position;
out vec4 outPosition;

void main() {
   outPosition = u_viewProjectionTransformMatrix * a_position;
}
```

And the code of my fragment shader:

```
#version 300 es

out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
    outColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
}
```

Pretty simple, right? But when I execute this code, I get the following error:

```
SceneKit: error, failed to link program: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '300' is not supported
ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error: #version
```

What did I do wrong? For your information, `#version 200 es` yields the same result so it does not seem to be related to the version of OpenGL per se.

Comment: Assign the context to the view's eaglContext property fixed it for me (as suggested by rickster). 

`let scnView = self.view as SCNView`
`let context = EAGLContext(API: .OpenGLES3)`
`scnView.eaglContext = context`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SceneKit uses an OpenGL ES 2.0 context by default.

If you want to use ES3 features (like `#version 300 es` shaders) you can create an [`EAGLContext`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/OpenGLES/Reference/EAGLContext_ClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/EAGLContext) object specifying OpenGL ES 3.0 as the API version, then assign it to your view's [eaglContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNView/eaglContext) property.

However, not all of SceneKit's renderer features support ES3, so you'll have to experiment to see if what you want to render works. Also keep in mind that ES3 requires an A7 GPU -- to support iPhone 4s/5/5c, iPad 4 and earlier, iPad mini (non-retina) and iPod touch, you'll need an ES2 rendering path.

If you're sticking to ES2 shaders, you're seeing an error because there's no `#version 200 es`. ES2 shaders use `#version 100`, or no `#version` directive at all (in which case 100 is implicit).

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I created a context using `let context = EAGLContext(API: .OpenGLES3)` and `EAGLContext.setCurrentContext(context)`. And I'm compiling for an iPad Air so it does have a A7 GPU.

`#version 100 es` gives the same error. And if I removed the `#version` directive, I have the following errors for the fragment shader: `error, failed to link program: ERROR: 0:1: Invalid storage qualifiers 'out' in global variable context` and `ERROR: 0:5: Use of undeclared identifier 'outColor'`. And similar errors for the vertex shader. It's like it does not know GLSL...

Comment: `#version 100` is legal GLSL. `#version 100 es` is not. If you're in GLSL ES 1.0 (which you implicitly are if you have no `#version` directive), the language is different -- `in` and `out` were introduced in GLSL ES 3.0. Any decent OpenGL ES 2.0 tutorial can tell you what to do there.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be doing `EAGLContext.setCurrentContext` -- assign your custom context to your `SCNView`'s `eaglContext` property.